# Any Airlines with Open ended tickets where Return can be determined later by design, or without a change fee?

Tags: tickets, airlines, bookings

Sometimes when I do extended travel I have no idea when I will be doing a return and would prefer to choose the return segment later.

- Not looking for Full Fare tickets {no change fee} or First class
- One ways (usually more expensive) than Return fare

**Examples:**

- I remember almost a decade back, a friend traveled India <> US via AI and had an open ended return ticket; he did not have to choose a return date/  hence no change fee to select his return.
- Apparently, a similar example was posted here about JAL.
  [Is there a way to check that the conditions on your plane ticket are actually what your travel agent said they are?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/is-there-a-way-to-check-that-the-conditions-on-your-plane-ticket-are-actually-wh?noredirect=1#comment110364_3623)
- Related Q&A:  [What is the best method of purchasing a ticket with an open return date?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-is-the-best-method-of-purchasing-a-ticket-with-an-open-return-date?rq=1)

Some history and information on Travel SE:

- [No more open returns?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/28925/no-more-open-returns?lq=1)

  > True open return tickets faded into obscurity last decade, my cobweb
  >   filled brain wants to say 2008 or 2009.
  >   .....................
  >   Open return tickets have faded away but they still exist in some
  >   airlines.
- More links coming..

### **Which airlines still offer this now in 2015?**

Please answer/ list airlines that you know still offer this, maybe directly, online or via travel agents.

Comment: Is there a specific sector that you wish to find this information for or is it a general query, Are you travelling India <> US too?

Comment: @skv - General  as well as specific. Lets take Asia <> US as an example. Either India or BKK or Asian hub.

Comment: Some special ticket like students' can change return without fee, but for normal one, NO. You pay what you get

Comment: Generally asking for lists has been considered broad... too many answers

Comment: Am I missing something obvious? Pretty much every airline offers open ended returns with no change fee. When you are willing to pay premium fees for your ticket in the first place. This is what business class tickets typically allow for.

Comment: @MarkMayo - Its not too broad as there are not many who do this. No one has yet named any so far.

Comment: @MastaBaba - I am not talking about Full Fare tickets. Please read properly. Let me link to some other questions I found on Open tickets.

Comment: @AlexS I said generally. Lists tend to generate single answers which don't answer the whole question, or partial answers.  Just noting it - it's up to you whether to change it, and up to the community what to do about it.

Comment: what air lines still sell open end tickets.

Answer (score 6):

Few airlines still sell open return tickets (that do not require reservations to be made). The exception is round-the-world and visit-a-continent fares which do still allow this.

However, virtually all of them sell changeable tickets that can be changed at any time. On the flip side it may not be cheap.

That said the ticket validity is usually limited to one year after date of purchase.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am not looking for Full Fare tickets. But, tickets where the RETURN end can be determined later, by design or without a change fee.

Comment: @AlexS That basically is a full fare ticket, at least in the return portion.

Comment: If you look at the 2 examples above, they are not Full fare examples. I am aware of full fare tickets and have even booked them few times.

Comment: @AlexS I don't believe these are common any more except for some very limited cases as I gave. I would add that even an open return ticket would require space in the appropriate booking class for the bought fare, and these days airlines aggressively close down the cheaper booking classes close to departure. So in principle you could have an "O" class deep-discount fare without a requirement to make reservations at ticketing time, but if the O booking code is closed on the flight you want, even with empty seats in the cabin, you would have to pay the fare difference up to the next fare.

Comment: - The long technicalities aside, I am wondering if any airlines still offer this, because even when I first heard about it from my friend it was NEWS to me. So, lets focus on which airlines do offer this, if at all.

Comment: @AlexS Fair enough, it's your question. I will leave my answer here until someone posts a list, if there are any such airlines that still do this on cheap return fares.

Comment: That is the question, and I doubt if there were many airlines who offered it before, and probably less or none offering that now.